# support GET more then 1000 record from dynamoDB

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Hi I want to support the option of GET more than 1000 records from DynamoDB and in addition add an option to send via APIgetaway a **list** of records to dynamodb.
(Both things are not possible at this moment).
Is there a way to do that? Is a suitable Lambda function is the only option?

Answer (score 2):

DynamoDB does not have a limit of getting up to 1000 items - I don't know what in the other layers you use impose this specific limit "1000".

If you want to read all items in the table, or all the items of a partition, you have the `Scan` and `Query` requests, respectively, which can bring you back even billions of records - but not in one call of course (you need to do consecutive requests, in what is known as *pagination*, and there is also the option for a parallel scan.

But it seems what you are really looking for is to read a bunch of unrelated items given their keys. The request for that is [BatchGetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html). This request is actually limited to just 100 item keys (much smaller than the limit you mentioned, 1000), and even that number 100 is only guaranteed to work if the items being read are fairly small - otherwise you go over the response size limit and get back responses for only some of the items. But this is hardly a problem - your application can always split up a 10,000-item request into 100 separate requests, sending all those batch requests in sequence or even in parallel.